# Unable to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, lts

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I launch the Software Updater, I am not prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Anyway, settings for the Software Updater are correct.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: lts -> lts is not available to 16.04.1 , the first point release.

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts

Answer (score 7):

I just did an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04 yesterday:

```
$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo update-manager -d
```

That should get you going... :)

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 is not supported **ATM**.

After the release of 16.04.**1**, you will be able to upgrade.